# Is my Siberian Husky's size normal

Tags: dogs, growing

Just wanted to know what you think of my Siberian husky. 
He is 3 months old: Weighs 15Kg
Is this normal?
[image: Frost]

[image: Frost and Rusty]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

15kg at 3 months and looking at your photos this seems fine for a male Husky. Male Huskies will typically grow to 20-27kg (45-60 pounds). At around 12 weeks/3 months they will be half of their adult weight.

If you are concerned that the Husky is a bit chubby, the telltale sign is that their waist is wider than their chest (when looking down from above). You could slowly and easily trim up the puppy a little by feeding less human food and giving a little more exercise. Remember as the dog grows it will have more muscle mass, greater stamina, and be able and willing to exercise for longer periods before fatigue sets in.